# How select data from two unrelated tables with a condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 unrelated tables in a SQLite database. I want to select rows which are vailed = True.
something like this;

```
Select * From Table1, Table2 Where Vaild = 'True'
```

table1

```
Name    ID      Valid

Sam     01      True
Jhon    02      False
Harry   03      False
Abby    04      False
Cody    05      True
```

table2

```
Name    ID      Valid

Jane    01      False
Lola    02      False
Charlie 03      False
Jack    04      False
Amelia  05      True
```

Result:

```
Name    ID      Valid

Sam     01      True
Cody    05      True
Amelia  05      True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use union all

```
select name, id, valid 
from Table1 where valid='True'
union all
select name, id, valid 
from Table2 where valid='True'
```

Answer (score 2):

use `union all`

```
Select Name, ID ,Valid From Table1 Where Vaild = 'True'
union all
Select Name, ID ,Valid From Table2 Where Vaild = 'True'
```